# Isolation on RS232 bus

Tags: opto-isolator, rs232, digital-isolator, isolator

Is there any "simple" way to get (1500V) galvanic isolation on RS232 (just RX and TX)? By isolating, I mean than I have 2 different grounds on each side of the insulation barrier.

On side A, I have 1.8V, 3.3V, 4.5V, and 5V rails, and can accept voltage ranges between (-4, +4) and (-15, +15). On side B, I only have 5V rail, and it should be something rather standard (the equipment on side B is for future use).

For logic level signals, it's quite easy to use a digital isolator (or even an opto-coupler).

However, I'm quite stuck with RS232, which goes bellow 0V.

The solution I found so far is convert RS232 to TTL, then pass the isolation, and convert back to RS232 : nothing difficult, but that makes 3 ICs and lots of PCB space. I even found some ICs doing RS232 to TTL and isolation in one step.

But for now, I haven't found a nice way to directly isolate RS232 signals.

Any idea?

Comment: @Justme I retracted that because I realized I wasn't sure if the OP needed galvanic isolation or just to be able to withstand some difference in the ground potential at both nodes.

Comment: Even if you only need TX and RX for data transfer, do you have the handshake pins available for positive and negative voltages?

Comment: @DKNguyen : I need galvanic isolation

Comment: @Justme : on the A side, I have an IMU, with just TX and RX pins (RS232) for an external sensor (so no handshake pins). Side B is the "outside" side, with a connector to add an external aiding sensor to the IMU (magnetometer, GNSS, odometer, ...)

Comment: Disclosure: I work at Analog Devices - we make a solution for this exact problem. Link: https://www.analog.com/en/product-category/isolated-rs-232.html

Comment: Tip: RS232 isn't a bus which suggests one to many communications. RS232 is point to point.

Comment: @MarkU : from what I understand from the datasheets, those components are doing RS232 to TTL + isolation, but don't go back to RS232 on the other side.

Comment: @Sandro You use a transceiver at each end for those ADI parts. But if you're trying to provide isolation to an unisolated RS-232 device that you have no control over at the far end, then this may an XY problem depending on where this 1500V is coming from.

Comment: @ DKNguyen : On the PCB, I have an IMU which communicates with the processor (both are referenced with respect to the isolated ground). I don't have the choice over the IMU sadly (imposed by management, I initially choose one far easier to integrate : it already escalated up to the CTO and CEO, so no way to change this). This IMU can be connected with a board to board connector to the PCB, but was designed to also work standalone (therefore RS232 instead of logic level signals). Having also PoE involved, I have to maintain the 1500Vrms with the outside.

Comment: So I know the choice of the IMU is "bad" from an electrical point of view, but sadly, it isn't in my power to change it.

Comment: if it's isolated, you don't know where 0V is, so how do you know the signal is below it? Optoisolator and pullup between -V and +V should work fine.

Comment: The issue is don't have only this interface towards the outside, but also several others, all sharing the same "external" ground. If you mean connecting the "GND" pin of the optocoupler /isolator to -12V (for example), it's a nice solution, excepted I don't have a negative voltage rail (and If I need to generate it, I'm not sure I gain something compared to one isolating transceiver + one non isolated transceiver)

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question. Deleting since it's N/A. @Voltage Spike's answer, while unfortunate, is probably the correct one.

Comment: Is it RS232 on both sides of the barrier, or is one side UART levels

Comment: @JasenСлаваУкраїні : I confirm, I need RS232 on both sides (which makes my use case atypical I guess, explaining why I can't find ICs dedicated to do the job)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen any solution simpler than RS232 chips to TTL, I think that is the way you'll have to go with an isolation design.

Answer (score 4):

You just need 2 optocouplers; one for Tx and one for Rx.

RS232 drivers should have enough current to drive an opto LED, it is just a question of where you connect the opto transistor. Generally you can get away with an signal that just swings between ground and 5V, so it is worth trying that. If you want a wider voltage swing, then you need a negative voltage  rail, which obviously can be created using a switchmode IC.

If you really must save on components, you could instead create the poor man's negative supply by charging up a capacitor to that voltage from an unused handshake line - this works fine on non-isolated interfaces, but might be a bit tricky when called upon to drive an opto LED - it depends how much current is needed.

Comment: Sure you can power the optocoupler LED from TXD pin. But how do you power the optocoupler receive side to make data wire have RS-232 level +/- voltages, if you don't have them? If there were these voltages available, then your suggestion would work.

Answer (score 4):

You could get the 3 chip solution down to a two chip solution by using a chip that has the isolation and RS232 transceiver in one chip.

If you put one isolated chip and one regular TTL to RS232 transciever back to back you can do the whole thing with two chips.

The [ADM3251E](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM3251E.pdf) made by Analog Devices is one example.  The chip also includes isolated power generation so you don't need a separate chip for that.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

assuming you need RS232 on both sides of the barrier There's basically four ways to do this.

A: use RS232 interface chips like MAX232 to convert to and from TTL level signals and opto-isolate those signals

B: double up the opto-isolators to allow them to pull both up and down.

C: ignore the fact that RS232 goes negative - if there is not much interferance the negative voltage typically isn't needed.

D: as C but with pull-down resistors so the output can go negative.

Comment: A: sounds reasonable, B: Why, single should be enough at RS-232 speeds, and you get ones with digital pushpull output too, the problem is getting positive and negative voltages C: It stops being RS-232 at that point, you might as well just use a 5V CMOS inverter D: better idea than C.

Comment: digital push-pull output will struggle with the minimal +/-3V swing required to meet the RS232 spec, so you're left with single-ended analogue parts.